# question regarding specific mod_rewrite syntax

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are other questions that are similar to this.. but I'm really struggling with mod_rewrite syntax so I could use some help.

Basically, what I am trying to do is have the following redirect occur:

`domain.com/1/` redirect to `domain.com/?id=$1` (also should work for `www.domain.com`)

What I have so far (that isn't working):

```
RewriteEngine On
ReRewriteRule ^/([0-9])$ /?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues.

First is terminology: if you want when a user types domain.com/1/ that the request is served by index.php?id=1, then you are rewriting /1/ to index.php?id=1, not the other way around as you said.

Second, simple typo: `RewriteRule`, not `ReRewriteRule`.

Second, `[0-9]` is the right way to match a number, but it'll only match a single digit. If you want to handle /13 then you should match one or more instances `[0-9]` by writing `[0-9]+`.

Third, the target of your rule should be the file you want to serve. `/` is not a file or an absolute URL, write out the `index.php` if that's what you mean.

Third, you say you want to handle `/1/`, but your rule says that the matched request must end in a number, not a slash. If you want to accept the slash whether it's there or not, put that in the rule.

`RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]`

Does that work?

Comment: this is very helpful.. but i'm actually getting a 404 error when going to domain.com/1/ .. also seperate issue. how can i include alphabetical/special characters (e.g. "ok.hi" or "hello") in the id as well?

Answer (score 1):

You've three issues:

`RewriteRule` is misspelt as point out by Michael, you need to worry about the trailing slash, and you need to stop processing rules when you've found the match:

```
RewriteRule ^/(\d+)/?$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled `RewriteRule`.  Otherwise, I think your syntax looks correct.

```
RewriteEngine On
ReRewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /?id=$1
--^^^---------
```

Actually, you should probably remove the `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9$_.+!*'(),-]+)$ /?id=$1
      ------^^^---------
```

**EDIT** Added the `+`.  Look at all the answers here. You need a composite of them., including the `+` and the `[L]` in addition to what I have here.

**EDIT2** Also edited to include alpha characters in the id.

**EDIT3** Added special characters to regex.  These should be valid in a URL, but it's unusual to find them there.

Comment: this is basically the solution. just looking for one addition - special characters in the id such as "." or "!". thanks for your help

Comment: @user628596 Added special characters.